# How to sync audio in blender 2.8?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I have a question. How to sync the audio with your actual video in blender 2.8 video editor, because when I found out that blender finally released, I was confused how to sync the audio and the work as I can't find the sync button.

Answer (score 4):

On the bottom left of the screen you will see Playback.. click that and right at the top of that pop up menu is a Synch sub menu.. I just had to find it myself :)